# Python: Extract matching word starts with number from a line using python

Tags: python, regex, shell

I want to read text file and find the words that starts with 5 in below text.

"Status": "OK"}], "PhysicalLocationString": "rack1/chassis_u1/cpu0/pcie_slot3", "Physloc": "0003000101010005", "PlaceholderNetworkDeviceFunctions": [{"FC HBA 1": "51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:E8"}, {"FC HBA 2": "51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:EA"}]}}, "PartNumber": "P9D94A", "SerialNumber": "MY57470DS8", "Status": {"Health": "OK", "HealthRollup": "OK", "State": "Enabled"}}

My output in another file should be

51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:E8
51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:EA

here is my code :

```
    import re
    import sys
    import os

    #get line
    with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/OP.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
    re.findall(r'\b[s]:\w+', line)
    matchedLine = line
        break


    #and write it to the file
    with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file.txt', 'w') as 
    file:
         file.write(matchedLine)
```

please help

Comment: This looks like JSON content, and therefore you should be using a JSON parser here, not a pure regex solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the edit from ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000.

Or:

```
print(" ".join(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('5'),your_string.split('"'))))
```

Output:

```
51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:E8 51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:EA
```

In newlines do:

```
print("\n".join(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('5'),your_string.split('"'))))
```

Comment: how to put into next line? like  51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:E8                                                                   51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:EA

Comment: first line should be 51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:E8 and second line should be 51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:EA

Comment: @RamKrishna Edited my answer

Comment: @RamKrishna Happy that i could help, 

Comment: You don't need the `list`. Just do `print("\n".join(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('5'),your_string.split('"'))))`

Comment: Hi @U9-Forward -  Now Im reading the file with the output                            
 16  16   011000   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:53:e8
  26  26   011a00   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03
  27  27   011b00   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07
  32  32   012000   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:54:80
  42  42   012a00   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01
 I want to write the word starting with 56 and not sure what to put end of line to select

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern

```
pattern = '"(5[^"]+)"'
re.findall(pattern, your_string)
```

It will search for a quote `"` followed by a 5, followed by anything except a quote, then end at the quote after that. The grouping will extract the number that you want.

Comment: giving error : pattern = "\"(5[^"]+)\""
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry about that! I fixed it with better quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
" ".join(e for e in your_string.split('"') if e.startswith("5"))
```